# Error handling on DBI->connect

Tags: perl, dbi

Besides handling error using standard code die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n" is it possible to write a custom code like below?

### Standard:

```
$dbstore = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw,
    {ora_session_mode => $mode, PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 0}) 
    or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

### Custom:

```
$dbstore = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw,
    {ora_session_mode => $mode, PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 0});

if (!$dbstore)
{
    CUSTOM_LOG_HANDLER("Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr");
    return;
}
```

### Sample Standard Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# PERL MODULES WE WILL BE USING
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

# HTTP HEADER
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

# CONFIG VARIABLES
$platform = "mysql";
$database = "store";
$host = "localhost";
$port = "3306";
$tablename = "inventory";
$user = "username";
$pw = "password";

#DATA SOURCE NAME
$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";

# PERL DBI CONNECT (RENAMED HANDLE)
$dbstore = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Are there any other ways to exit gracefully without errors getting logged into the web server logs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can always use a custom error handler with the DBI:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

sub handle_error {
    my $message = shift;
    #write error message wherever you want
    print "the message is '$message'\n";
    exit; #stop the program
}

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:foo",
    "user",
    "pass",
    {
        PrintError  => 0,
        HandleError => \&handle_error,
    }
) or handle_error(DBI->errstr);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from doesntexist");
```

That said, you should be logging errors, and for a web application, the web server's logs makes sense.  If you are worried about the amount of noise in your web logs, you should concentrate on fixing the errors, not making the logs less noisy by removing sources of information.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What should be the value of PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 ?

Comment: Example will this code work?

$dbstore = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw,
    {ora_session_mode => $mode, PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0, HandleError => \&handle_error_and_exit})
    or handle_error_and_exit("Could not connect to $user/$pw: $DBI::errstr");

Comment: RaiseError is off by default, and if you want to not send messages to STDERR you should leave it off.  PrintError is on by default, which is why I turned it off.  In the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#HandleError) it says "If the subroutine returns a false value then the RaiseError and/or PrintError attributes are checked and acted upon as normal.", so as long as the function returns a true value (or `exit`s), then neither PrintError or RaiseError should have any affect.